Number of Ring Homomorphisms from $ \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{F}_p $
I am trying to determine the number of ring homomorphisms from the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]  \to  \mathbb{F}_p $, where $ p $ is a prime number in the set $ \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19\} $.
I understand that a ring homomorphism $ \varphi: \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{F}_p $ must satisfy the condition $ \varphi(i)^2 = -1 $. This means that we need to find elements $ x \in \mathbb{F}_p $ such that
$$
x^2 = -1.
$$
For example: Suppose $p=2,$ then $X^2 = -1$ has no solutions, since $1^2 = 1$ and $-1=1.$ This implies that for $p=2$ there are no ring homomorphims.
On the other hand, if $p=5,$ then $p \equiv 1 \mod 4.$ Hence $x^2=-1$ has two solutions, namely $x=2$ and $x=3,$ since $2^2 = 4 \equiv -1 \pmod 5$ and $3^2 = 9 \equiv -1 \pmod 5.$ This means that there are two ringhomomorphisms.
Thus, I would like to know:
Is my reasoning correct? If not, can someone provide a detailed explanation?
Thank you!

Your reasoning is correct.

I would check your arguments. You say $x^2 = -1$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{F}_2$, and then show $1^2 = -1$ :) .

Your reasoning is correct except for $p=2$, where there is exactly one homomorphism. For prime $p>2$, $-1$ is a square mod $p$ iff $p\equiv1\bmod4$ and if so, it has two square roots $\bmod p$.

I am going to go against the grain and say that I think you probably need to say a little bit more. It's true that $\varphi$ must satisfy $\varphi(i)^2 = -1$. But this only gives you an upper bound - you need the stronger statement "if $R$ is a unital ring then a homomorphism $\varphi: \Bbb Z[i] \to R$ corresponds exactly to a choice of a square root of unity in $R$ (by identifying $\varphi$ with $\varphi(i)$)". You should be a bit clearer that this is what you're using, and depending on what you're allowed to quote, you might need to give a short proof!

@DrTokus This was not explicit, but clear from your sayings ("$X^2=−1$
has no solution... implies...no ring homomorphims", "two solutions...means that there are two ringhomomorphisms".
